# NDB map(callback, produces_cursors=True)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

The Google AppEngine NDB Documentation for map() states that:

> "All query options keyword arguments are supported."

However, I have tried to use `produces_cursors=True` on `map()` and I'm not getting a cursor back.

```
map(callback, pass_batch_into_callback=None, merge_future=None, **q_options)
```

I'd like to use `map()` as I can set the callback to a tasklet.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queryclass#kwdargs_options

Edit - Providing code sample:

```
@ndb.tasklet
def callback(user):
    statistics = yield ndb.Key(Statistics, user.key.id()).get_async()
    raise ndb.Return(user, statistics)

result = User.query().map(callback, produces_cursors=True)
```

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet?

Comment: Sure @bossylobster , I've added some sample code.

Comment: Indeed you are correct, `tasklets.MultiFuture` only returns a list (http://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/source/browse/ndb/tasklets.py?r=437f5437d9fba7b1c470d56ed2fdf5633d406730#562) and `map_query` doesn't keep any of the cursor information around.

Comment: Hi @Chris it appears to me that you managed to get the cursors somehow working, in my case even without having typos something is going wrong. I have described it elaboratly here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21118732/query-cursor-for-app-engine-in-python-using-query-iterator   May be you can spot something obvious that's getting overlooked by me. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @HarshalPatil - Guido mentions below that map() doesn't return cursors, does that help?

Comment: It's true that map doesn't return cursors, but the query iterator should have them, as per documention. Has this ever worked for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example seems to have a typo -- the correct flag is `produce_cursors`, not `produces_cursors`.

But cursors are only made available when you use an iterator, not with `map()`.  Check out the async iterators example; it's a little bit of work but you can definitely use it to manually create a tasklet for each result.